# Typescript and React with complex prop type interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to both React and Typescript and have been working on a project so far with React only. I am now in the process of adding/converting the project to Typescript and am coming up against a wall in my conversion and despite several attempts at googling have been unable to find an answer. I have the following props defined for a component:

```
interface Item {
    Text: JSX.Element,
    Link: string
}

interface TCLBProps {
    Icon: JSX.Element,
    Header: string,
    Items: Item[]
}

const TwoColumnLinkBlock: React.FC<TCLBProps> = (props) => {
```

I then have another component (in another file) that is attempting to invoke the TwoColumnLinkBlock component defined above.

```
<TwoColumnLinkBlock
    Icon={<Resources color="brand" size="medium" />}
    Header="Inputs & Incoming Data"
    Items={linkSet1}
/>
```

linkSet1 is defined as:

```
let linkSet1 : Item[] = [
       {Text: <span><b>Test</b></span>, Link: "/TestPage"},
       {Text: <span><b>Test2</b></span>, Link: "/TestPage2"},
    ];
```

Typescript tells me that it cannot find Item. If I export the item and import it here, I am told that "Item refers to a value but is being used as a type here."

What am I misunderstanding about this process? Is my interface declared incorrectly?

Edit: Example https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-mirzakhani-0ggwn

This follows the same structure I've been using. You can see, although it compiles and runs, Typescript is balking on WidgetItem when it's used in index.tsx. In my Visual Studio copy, I get the error described above at this same line.

Comment: Based on what you have posted I don't see any problem. Can you include how are you exporting/importing the `Item` type. And maybe a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I pasted your code into a `.tsx` file and no errors were raised. I think you bug may be somewhere else. Also you may be able to save yourself some keystrokes and define your function more simply: `function TwoColumnLinkBlock(props: TCLBProps) { ... }`

Comment: @JohnnyZabala - Added code sandbox sample that shows the code structure I'm using. The error sandbox produces isn't identical but its the same line oddly enough.

Comment: @AlexWayne Thanks for the tip! I was wondering if there was a more expedient way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code provided in your Codesandbox you have the `src/components/Widget/index.tsx` file with:

```js
import Widget from "./widget";
import WidgetItem from "./widget";

export { Widget };
export { WidgetItem };

export default Widget;
```

And the `src/components/Widget/widget.tsx` file with:

```js
export interface WidgetItem {
  Text: JSX.Element;
  Link: string;
}

// Other contents

export default widget;
```

The component (`widget`) is the default export so it is imported with `import AnyNameYoudLike from "./widget"`. But the `interface WidgetItem` is a named export and can only be imported with the exact name as `import { WidgetItem } from "./widget"`.

Note these top two imports in the first `index.tsx` file. These are both different names but they are **both importing the same default component.** The `WidgetItem` is a named import so musted be imported as `import { WidgetItem } from "./widget";`.

So the `WidgetItem` being exported is actually the component as well (and not the interface).

[Here is the Codesandbox with the fix](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-khorana-udrj1).

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot. Your explanation of what the import does without the  { } is something I did not know and makes total sense now. Unfortunately for me, I now get a "Cannot re-export a type when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provded." error in my actual project - but I assume that has to do with the secondary index.ts I'm using. This leads me to question the nested index structure I'm using. I found it in an example project at one point, but I wonder if there's a better way to structure child components like this?

Comment: I would suggest researching that flag and determine if you want to/need to have that enabled. It might not make sense for your use case.